# Same-origin Policy Specification

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have a javascript AJAX call made to a code behind function running on my server, which returns to the client script (that has initiated the call), a url (from a different Domain than mine) with a query (http://www.web_server_url.com/my_query&callback=?). After returning the call, the following JQuery code is executed ('specific_div' being an existing div in the page):

```
$('#specific_div').load(returned_url);
```

Meanwhile, I obtain the following error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.web_server_url.com/my_query&callback=?. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Although I understand the same-origin policy, I do not quite understand why I am obtaining this error message in this scenario since the url is passed from my server. Shouldn’t it be accepted by the browser, considering that its origin is from the same Domain (local host in this case), although it is contacting another Domain?

Comment: `Shouldn’t it be accepted by the browser, considering that its origin is from the same Domain (local host in this case), although it is contacting another Domain?` No.  You can't send a request to another domain.

Comment: What about [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)?

Comment: Consider for a minute that AJAX requests are made on behalf of the client.  They will pass along any browser cookies.  I could easily make a webpage that upon being viewed would make AJAX requests from your browser to every known banking or financial institution requesting to transfer money to a shady account or something.  If you are currently logged into any of those websites then your browser would pass the cookie and the request would be authenticated.

Comment: So just because you read an HTTP response from a website doesn't mean you trust it to communicate on your behalf!

Comment: Thank you Trevor. Makes sense. Without using CORS, would you know how would one implement what I am trying to achieve? (From my understanding CORS is not supported by all browsers, and thus I was trying to avoid using it.)

Comment: Load the data server side and feed it to your client.

Comment: Since you are loading the data into a div it's probably just HTML, you could use an IFRAME too.

Comment: Thank you again Trevor. Initially, this is what I was trying to implement, but the data is returned in the following format: document.write('<iframe src="//www.other_domain_url.com/some_data"></iframe>'); Won’t this generate the same error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same origin means requested resource/information must be on the same domain (schema + host + port) as page. It does not mean "url to resource provided by the origin server".

In your particular case you have page on `"http://localhost"` and trying to request `"http://www.web_server_url.com"` - scheme ("http") and port (80) match, but domain name does not ("localhost" vs. "www.web_server_url.com").

Note that error you see explains that you need to enable [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORS) on destination server for this particular request.

If you don't own/control destination server (and hence can't use CORS or JSONP to securely communicate with other server client side) than you most generic option is proxy that request on your server. Note that limits on what information you can use (i.e. you can't steal cookies set on the destination domain this way).

Comment: Thank you Alexei. From my understanding, CORS is not yet supported by all browsers, and thus, I was trying to avoid using this technology. What I do not understand is that I have a script tag in the page, which contacts the same url (but with a different query at the end), and which works fine upon initially loading the page. Shouldn’t sending the page an updated url be considered the same-origin (since the url is sent by my server), as the initial one? Am I missing something?

Comment: @JF001 You are describing the common security flaw called [cross site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).  The difference is that AJAX requests can be PUT, POST, etc., while something like a <script> or <img> tag is an HTTP GET request.  GETs shouldn't cause any harm but many websites are poorly created and GETs can cause harm.  This has been the cause of fraud in the past.

Comment: Thank you again Trevor. How would one achieve what I am trying to do without using CORS? Surely, some sites must be doing what I am trying to implement in a secure way.

Comment: @JF0001 - I've added standard "proxy request server side" workaround to the answer.

Comment: Thank you again Alexei. As indicated above in a comment, this is what I was initially trying to implement, but the data is returned in the following format: document.write('<iframe src="//www.url.com/some_data"></iframe>'); Won’t this generate the same error message considering that it refers back to an external url?